# Getting an error “A task was canceled.” when processing a large record set in Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, entity-framework, parallel-processing

I am using Parallel.Invoke to call a large array of Actions on a 4 core machine. 
Each action makes a call to an external web api to retrieve a json package of info. That json package is then de-serialized into a series of objects. Each of those objects is then inserted into several tables via EntityFramework 6.

This will process around 2 thousand distinct IDs so I am trying to use the Parallel library to get as fast a through-put as possible.

My main:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    var apiKey = "myKey";
    List<string> caseIDs = new List<string>();
    //read list of ids from DB
    using (var db = new StagingContext())
    {
        caseIDs = db.BatchList.Where(b => b.CaseID!=null).Select(a => a.CaseID).Distinct().Take(5000).ToList();
    }
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    foreach (var id in caseIDs)
    {
        var UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid();
        actions.Add(() => GetRecords(id,"https://myAPIURL/{0}?api={1}&case={2}", apiKey, UniqueID));               
    }
    ParallelOptions op = new ParallelOptions
    {
        CancellationToken = tok.Token,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
    };
    Parallel.Invoke(op, actions.ToArray());           
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

My action:

```
private static void GetRecords(string CaseID, string url, string apiKey, Guid UniqueID)
{
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
   {
    var tmpUrl = string.Format(url, apiKey, CaseID);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var result = client.GetAsync(tmpUrl).Result;
    var jsonString = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    jsonString.Wait();
    var myObjectList = new List<MyObject>();
    if (!jsonString.Result.Contains("error"))
    {
       myObjectList.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(jsonString.Result));
       foreach (var item in myObjectList)
       {
           item.UniqueID = UniqueID;
       }
    }
   //Write this out to DB
    using (var db = new StagingContext())
    {
        var myMappedObjectList = myObjectList.Adapt<List<MyObject>>();
        db.CaseAttributeHistories.AddRange(myMappedObjectList);
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
        {
        db.SaveChanges();
        scope.Complete();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When I process a smaller set of data, ~1000 records, it works pretty good. When I process a larger data set , >1400, I often get an

> “A task was canceled.”

error.

I am new to the Parallel & multi-threading.

- Is this a valid approach?
- Is there a good way to track down what is
  causing the cancellation?
- How would I handle/ignore the error and
  continue with the rest of the records?
- Is there a better or faster pattern to use in this situation?

Comment: Have you though of using async and await C# 5 features.

Comment: Even though HttpClient implements `IDisposable`, it is recommended to create a single instance and use that in all of your calls.  Recommend removing your HttpClient from the using statement and try using a single static instance for all requests as seen here.  https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Can I ask why you are not using await and instead calling Result property on var result = client.GetAsync(tmpUrl).Result; Also why dont you make your GetRecords method async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check for Exceptions. Swallowing a Exception is a deadly sin of exception handling. And unfortunately Multithreading does that fully automatically. Normally you have to write code for that. In mutltithreading you have to write code to **avoid** it. I would advise those two articles on Exception handling before you try your hand at Multithreading:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Secondly, doing sequential calls to a Web API is generally a bad idea. Please verify that you do not have a way to retrieve the data in bulk, rather then piecemeal. Piecemeal retreival often incurs more overhead then data.

Third, are you even allowed to automate it on that scale? If the APi provider wants no bulk retreival, he might not want automation on that scale. If so he might notice the sudden increase in load and apply some load-throteling later. That could kill your programm.

Fourth, Multithreading a APi call will propably not speed things up. The WEB API and Network will be the bottleneck with a very high propability. Multithreading only helps with CPU bottlenecked operations. With Network, Disk, DB and similar operations, there will be often 0 performance incraese. Or even a performance **decrease**, as the multiple operations get in each others way.

A bit of Multitasking (even just a single alternate Thread) is mandatory with Network, Disk and similar longrunning opeations. But actuall Multithreading rarely to never helps.

Comment: I sort of disagree with your fourth bullet point in that you can get way quicker at processing a bunch of unrelated API calls.  In our instance, we found that a single call to an API endpoint took on average 200ms (connect, request, download, close connection).  The call itself may have a total payload of 5KB, way below any network thresholds.  However, by making 5 calls in parallel, we essentially would get 5 returns in the same amount of time as the API server can handle multiple concurrent requests.  This method worked extremely well for lots of small API requests.

Comment: That is why I only said "propably". Latest when the other side notices it and adds some load throthling (only one request per account or IP adress active at the same time), this speed increase will vanish. And latest when multiple instances on multiple computers in multiple networks spam that API, the provider will notice it.

Comment: Not all API request calls are to someone else's stuff or the same domain even.  Even then, most APIs have calls/min or calls/sec type throttling and not simultaneous calls.  Your original assertion has nothing to do with what someone else may or may not do with their inbound connections rather that you will bottleneck your network.  Unless you are trying to download 20 copies of a UNIX iso at once, multiple simultaneous network connections will most often increase performance speeds over doing them serially.  Just my opinion, we are free to disagree.

Comment: He is free to make suboptimal decisions despite the information I gave him. Maybe it works. Maybe it backfires horribly, invalidating weeks of work. That is his perogative. Between the two of us we have given him the full picture to the best of our abilities.

Comment: In this particular case it was suggested by the API provider. I was aware of the possibility of throttling and /or potentially looking like some sort of an attack.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the exception is being thrown from `client.GetAsync`?

`HttpClient` will throw `TaskCanceledException` when the HTTP call times out. (i.e. the web service is not responding)

Annoying, I know.

It's possible that, because you're hitting it so hard, it can't keep up. You can try raising the [`Timeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_Timeout) property of your `HttpClient`, but the default is already 100 seconds.

If you want to just ignore those errors, then wrap the `client.GetAsync(tmpUrl)` in a try/catch block and just `return` (and maybe log it somewhere).